# Scifi anthology published in the '70s including “The Enchanted Village” and “All Summer in a Day”

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

The anthology contains short stories including, "The Enchanted Village" by A E Van Vogt, "All Summer in a Day", by Ray Bradbury, "And He Built a Crooked House", by Heinlein (?), and other great stories, including a story about a political (?) prisoner who escapes and has a chip in his head, and is helped by a doctor while hitch-hiking.   The book has a red and blue cover (mostly red, I think).  I read it as a kid in the 70's and would love to find it again to reread.

Answer (score 10):

I think you are looking for the anthology *Science Fiction*, published in 1973 and edited by Sylvia Brodkin and Elizabeth Pearson. According to [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?29072), it has a mostly-red cover with some blue, and contains the van Vogt and Heinlein stories you mention. However, it does not contain that Bradbury; the one it does have is "A Sound Of Thunder".

[image: Cover of Science Fiction]

Comment: That's it!  Thank you, you are a gem.  I'd been googling info and searching for the name for months.  Now all I have to do is find a copy somewhere.  Thanks again, much appreciated.